# How can I list tabulars in the contents, or make tables with invisble captions

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, captions

Is there a way to have simple tabulars be listed in the list of tables? I'd even put them in by hand if I knew how..

My tables look like this right now:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l c l}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{LB medium} \\
1\% w/v & & tryptone \\
0.5\% w/v & & yeast extract \\
0.5\% w/v & & NaCl \\
 & & \\
 & & \\
\end{tabular}

\quad

\begin{tabular}{l c l}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{LB$_{Amp}$-Agarplate, pH 7} \\
1\% w/v & & tryptone \\
0.5\% w/v & & yeast extract \\
0.5\% w/v & & NaCl \\
1,5\% w/v & & Agar-Agar \\
0,01\% w/v & & Ampicillin \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

If I change it to a `table` environment, the caption is below the table and has a section number in front of it, which messes up my formatting and just doesn't look good.
Is there a way to make captions completely invisible in the text and list it in the contents? Or insert a completely invisble table (caption included) and list that in the list of tables?

Comment: Can you provide a full MWE starting with `\documentclass{}` and ending with `\end{document}`? This would increase your chance to get an appropriate answer. BTW Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Thanks, well I'm using the Thesis Template from writelatex.com. I've set up a small test document there https://www.writelatex.com/342782sgvqqj you can see 4 tables down in chapter one. I'd be happy if I could at least avoid the linebreaks in the captions on the bottom two tables. Ideally I would like it all to look like the top two tables yet still be listed in the list of tables.

Comment: If you increase the width of the `minipage`s you can avoid the line breaks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
\addcontentsline{lof}{table}{<text>}
```

to add `<text>` in the LoF, having the same formatting as a regular table entry; a complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\listoftables

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l c l}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{LB medium} \\
1\% w/v & & tryptone \\
0.5\% w/v & & yeast extract \\
0.5\% w/v & & NaCl \\
 & & \\
 & & \\
\end{tabular}\quad
\begin{tabular}{l c l}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{LB$_{Amp}$-Agarplate, pH 7} \\
1\% w/v & & tryptone \\
0.5\% w/v & & yeast extract \\
0.5\% w/v & & NaCl \\
1,5\% w/v & & Agar-Agar \\
0,01\% w/v & & Ampicillin \\
\end{tabular}
\addcontentsline{lot}{table}{Some caption for the list of figures}
\addcontentsline{lot}{table}{Some other caption for the list of figures}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I find this to be rather strange (having a caption in the LoF, but no text in the document), so perhaps I misunderstood the question.

Comment: @DanMan Glad I could help. Don't forget that you can accept the answer by clicking the checkmark to its left; in case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).